# after4 - Simple python task (index and list issues)

Tags: python

this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow. It has been really valuable to me while I have been learning python 2.7

The question is as follows:

"Given a non-empty list numlist of ints, write a function after4(numlist) that returns a new list containing the elements from the original numlist that come after the last 4 in the original numlist. The numlist will contain at least one 4.

```
after4([2, 4, 1, 2]) → [1, 2]
after4([4, 1, 4, 2]) → [2]
after4([4, 4, 1, 2, 3]) → [1, 2, 3]"
```

I believed the question to be rather simple but I just can seem to get the code right for what I had planned in my head.

```
  def after4(numlist):
    """
    Given a list of numbers, will print all numbers after the last 4
    :param x: list - list of numbers including the 4
    :return: list - New list of all numbers after the last 4
    """
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(numlist) if x == 4]
    index = max(indices) 
    print x[index:]
```

But I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to work around it.
'int' object has no attribute 'getitem'" (the error is on the final line of the code "print x[index:]")

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(x) if j==4 ]` Edit this and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, previous implementation was wrong. This is correct :)

```
def after4(x):
    rev = list(reversed(x))         #rev = it's reversed list
    start = len(x) - rev.index(4)   #start = it's index of last 4,  len(x) - length of list
    print x[start:]
```

In method `index(x, y)`:

x - searching element (here it's 4)

y - index from we want start searching, if we skip this argument it starts from index 0.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, this was a different approach to what I had envisioned but a much more efficient one at that. Thanks once again

Comment: @GarvanDoyle My pleasure :)

Comment: Hey do you mind briefly explaining how 'start = x.index(4,n-1)' works. I understand how list.index(obj) works but I am unsure what happens when you add the comma and another variable.

Comment: @GarvanDoyle Sorry the previous implementation was wrong, this one is correct. I mistaked the second parameter of index() function.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 1):

You use the name `x` for two different purposes: as the list parameter for the function `after4()` and as an integer in the list comprehension for the variable `indices`.

The interpreter thinks you mean the integer one in the last line, but you mean the list parameter one. Change one of those names to a different name and see what happens.

You should use more descriptive variable names from now on. For example, instead of using `x` for the list parameter, use something like number_list, which makes it clear just what it is. Keep short names like `x` for mathematical parameters (such as math.sin(x)) and for list comprehensions.

Comment: The error still persists, I changed the functions parameter to numlist and changed it within the indices line also. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes indeed they must. Pardon the ignorance but did I change it like you suggested or did I misunderstand?